# solving a second-order non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good day. Could you help me to solve the DE

$$
y''=\sqrt{1+y'^2}
$$

I have tried to write the equation in terms of $y'=z, y''=z'$, which results in the new DE
$$
z'=\sqrt{1+z^2}
$$

but then I got some problem..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try separation of variables

$$
\int\limits_{z_0}^z \frac{d\zeta}{\sqrt{1+\zeta^2}} = \int\limits_{x_0}^x d\xi
$$

then solve for $z$.